# Shorter runtime of `random.shuffle` when using `random.random` as keyword argument in Python3

Tags: python, random, python-3.x, runtime, shuffle

I just observed that when using Python3 the shuffling of a list with `random.shuffle` needs approximately half the runtime when explicitly submitting the function `random.random` for the `random` keyword argument. I checked whether Python2 has the same problem but found that it only occurs with Python3.

I use the following code to measure the runtime of the two versions:

```
from timeit import Timer
t1 = Timer("random.shuffle(l)", "import random; l = list(range(100000))")
t2 = Timer("random.shuffle(l, random = random.random)", "import random; l = list(range(100000))")
print("With default rand: %s" % t1.repeat(10,1))
print("With custom rand: %s" % t2.repeat(10,1))
```

I made a [testcase at ideone](http://ideone.com/VdP5dh) for you to see with Python3 and the same code with [Python2](http://ideone.com/pfoHcg).

According to the [documentation for shuffle](http://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) the same function `random.random` is used in the default case when I omit the optional keyword argument `random`, so there should be no difference when I give it the same function to generate the random number as in the default case.

I checked the respective sources (Python2 vs. Python3) for the `shuffle` function in the `Lib/random.py` folders and found that they behave the same way *if* I explicitly call the Python3 version with a function for the `random` keyword. If I omit this argument, Python3 uses the helper function `_randbelow` so there should be the root for my problem. I can't see why Python3 uses `_randbelow` because it slows `shuffle` down. As far as I understand it, its benefit lies in generating arbitrary large random numbers, but it should not slow down my shuffling of a list that has way fewer than 2^32 elements (100000 in my case).

Can anyone explain to me why I'm seeing such a difference in the runtimes although they should be closer together when I use Python3?

P.S.: Please note that I'm not interested why runtime with Python2 is better than with Python3, but the difference in runtime when using the argument `rand=rand.rand` argument in Python3 versus not using it in Python3 only.

Answer (score 4):

The docstring in the function `random.shuffle` contradicts the code.
In python 2.7.2+ the docstring is correct:

```
    def shuffle(self, x, random=None, int=int):
    """x, random=random.random -> shuffle list x in place; return None.

    Optional arg random is a 0-argument function returning a random
    float in [0.0, 1.0); by default, the standard random.random.
    """

    if random is None:
        random = self.random
    for i in reversed(xrange(1, len(x))):
        # pick an element in x[:i+1] with which to exchange x[i]
        j = int(random() * (i+1))
        x[i], x[j] = x[j], x[i]
```

But in Python 3.2 we find:

```
def shuffle(self, x, random=None, int=int):
    """x, random=random.random -> shuffle list x in place; return None.

    Optional arg random is a 0-argument function returning a random
    float in [0.0, 1.0); by default, the standard random.random.
    """

    randbelow = self._randbelow
    for i in reversed(range(1, len(x))):
        # pick an element in x[:i+1] with which to exchange x[i]
        j = randbelow(i+1) if random is None else int(random() * (i+1))
        x[i], x[j] = x[j], x[i]
```

So the docstring still tells the old story, but now the default function used is random.randbelow